# Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone ( sorting hat)

Tags: phrase-meaning

'And now, before we go to bed, let us sing the school song!' cried Dumbledore.

'Ah, music,' he said, wiping his eyes.

Did Dumbledore really cry....?

Comment: Please look up the verb to cry. It is not only about tears. You need to post some proof of research in your questions and I think this one would not have been a question if you had looked up this verb. Be so kind as to properly capitalize letters in English. Thanks.

Comment: @lambie ..I apologize....can you point out where I went wrong with capitalizing

Comment: The title, I have fixed it for you.

Answer (score 3):

There are two definitions of [**cry**](http://cry!wiktionary) going on here. In chronological order, they are:

> 2. (*transitive*) To utter loudly; to call out; to declare publicly.

Dumbledore *called out*, "Let us sing the school song!"

> 1. (*intransitive*) To shed tears; to weep.

Dumbledore felt emotional about the music, and the emotion made him cry. Or, more accurately, it made his eyes "mist up" or "water," which means the tear ducts activated *slightly* and made his eyes were wet, but he did not *weep*.